# List of file in sdcard returning some null values with json

Tags: android, json

```
public class FileUtil {

public static String getJson(Context context,String path) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray files = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray directory = new JSONArray();
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

            JSONObject entry=new JSONObject();              
            entry.put("name", listOfFiles[i].getName());
            entry.put("path", listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            entry.put("size", readableFileSize(listOfFiles[i].length()));
            entry.put("dateModified",readabledateMod(listOfFiles[i]) );     

            files.put(i, entry);

        } else {

            JSONObject entry=new JSONObject();      
            entry.put("name", listOfFiles[i].getName());
            entry.put("path", listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            entry.put("size", readableFileSize(listOfFiles[i].length()));
            entry.put("dateModified",readabledateMod(listOfFiles[i]) );
            entry.put("filesNumber", Integer.toString(listOfFiles[i].listFiles().length));
          //entry.put("directorySize",readableFileSize(folderSize(listOfFiles[i])));

            directory.put(i, entry);
        }
    }
    jo.put("files", files);
    jo.put("directory",directory);
    return jo.toString();
 }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
"files":
[
null,null,
{"path":"\/sdcard\/json.txt","dateModified":"21\/09\/2014","size":"196B","name":"json.txt"},
null,null,null, 
{"path":"\/sdcard\/a.txt","dateModified":"28\/09\/2014","size":"3 B","name":"a.txt"},
null,null
],

"directory":
..............................
.........................
}
```

I am trying to get file list in json format.Working fine with arraylist but with json it gives me some null values...
Why returning some values null how can I fixed this I try entry.equals(null) but all those not working please help

Comment: entry.equals(null) can never be true, because if entry is null, it throws a nullpointerexception. Use entry == null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this

```
files.put(i, entry);
```

You use the index of the complete list as the index to place the entry. So for each directory it finds, you skip one place in the file list.

Just use

```
files.put(entry);
```

Of course, the same goes for `directory.put(i, entry);`

Comment: You should select this as answer if it worked for you.